# PAIN. Comments Pagination

Tags: comments, pagination

Sorry for flame, but i wasted 7-12 hours trying to understand how comments pagination works....
Never thought that simple step will take that much with WordPress :'((((

i output comments in my theme like this:

```
wp_list_comments(
      array(
         'callback' => 'regular_comment',
         'avatar_size' => 100,
         'style'       => 'ol',
         'short_ping'  => true,
         'reply_text'  => __( 'Reply', 'twentyseventeen' ) . ' ' . '<img class="comments-icon" src="' . get_path() . '/assets/i/others/chat.svg">',
           )
      );
```

And trying to use

```
echo paginate_comments_links();
```

for outputting pagination. Now after many hours of trying i understood that there is no way to use paginated comments unless you select that option in admin under Settings->Discussion.....

set_option('page_comments');

**If that option is not set** - no matter how hard i try to get total comments and set 'per_page' arg for wp_list_comments() - pagination urls ([http://my-site.com/post-1/comment-page-{N}/#comments](http://my-site.com/post-1/comment-page-%7BN%7D/#comments) simply won't work - url just redicts to http://my-site.com/post-1

So, i have to setup that option... but. If you let's say want on one page to show 5 comments per page and 10 on another, then you use 'per_page' for wp_list_comments(), right ?

```
wp_list_comments( ...args, 'per_page' => 5)
```

while in admin panel we have let's say 10. After setting this up we need to tell **paginate_comments_links()** total number of comments on pages, because otherwise it will count using values provided in admin settings(under Settings->Discussion)
So,

```
paginate_comments_links( array( 'total' => count_number_some_way ) )
```

In this case we will get pagination numbers as we want, but pagination will only work for pages defined in admin panel.... comments now show up on page according to 'per_page' argument for wp_list_comments, but pagination still works only for values in admin panel... It does show different number of pages. For example, we have 12 total comments on post, defined 6 per page in admin panel and now want to display 2 per page via 'per_page' argument, so pagination number will increase from 1..2 to 1..2..3..4..5..6. But only 1..2 will work, other links will just output no comments...

**Solution.**
I've solved this by using **get_comments()** with **'number'** and **'offset'** arguments.

You will need to count comments by **wp_count_comments( post_id )->approved**, then output pagination using any suitable for you pagination function. And last but not least disable redirection for this particular post_type to make get_query_var($paged) functionality work

When using get_comments function you get full controll for quering comments, since it's a function that utilizes WP_Comment_Query Class. You can ASC DESC comments in any way you want, query with different parametrs, etc.

Comment: I've solved this by using get_comments with 'number' and 'offset' arguments. You will need to count comments by wp_count_comments( post_id )->approved, then output pagination using any suitable for you pagination function. And last but not least disable redirection for this particular post_type to make get_query_var($paged) functionality work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do? Why do you need to _force_ pagination even if the user has not enabled it? Also, your solution isn't going to support threaded replies.

Comment: regardless of the flame, you got me to my fix as I didn't know that this needed to be activated. So thank you.